Do eternal ordinances such as the festival of unleavened bread pose a biblical contradiction?
According to the LES, Exodus 12:14 says,

"And this day shall be a memorial for you, and you shall celebrate it as a festival to the Lord for all your generations; you shall celebrate it as an eternal ordinance"

If Jesus was the fulfillment of the passover and did away with the sacrificial system and festivals, wouldn't the festival of unleavened bread NOT be considered an eternal ordinance therefore posing a contridiction in the text?

There is no contradiction. Please share how you arrived at the statement that Yeshua "did away with the festivals".

Let's start with the Hebrew. The term “eternal” (Hebrew: עוֹלָם, olam) can mean “lasting for an age” or “perpetual” in certain contexts. The Strong's defines it as:

Definition: long duration, antiquity, futurity

It does not necessarily imply something must remain in the same form. Thus, the festival’s eternal nature may be understood as enduring in its fulfilled form through Christ.
Think about it in this manner: Jesus did not abolish the original command but transformed it.




Festival of Unleavened Bread
Fulfillment in Jesus




Removal of Leaven
Leaven (yeast) symbolizes sin and corruption. Leaven is removed from homes to signify purity and holiness.
Jesus lived a sinless life, free from corruption. His purity fulfills the symbolism of the removal of leaven (1 Peter 2:22).


Sacrifice of the Lamb
The Passover lamb is sacrificed, and its blood marks the homes of the Israelites, sparing them from judgment.
Jesus is the ultimate Passover Lamb, whose sacrifice spares believers from judgment (1 Corinthians 5:7). His blood marks the new covenant.


Memorial of Deliverance
The festival commemorates the Israelites’ deliverance from slavery in Egypt.
Jesus’ death, burial, and resurrection deliver believers from the slavery of sin and death (Romans 6:22).



Perhaps we could even say that the purpose of the festival is fulfilled and continued in the life of a Christian through Jesus. Finally, Jesus refers to Himself as the Bread of Life (John 6:35). His body, broken for us, is symbolized by the unleavened bread used in communion (Luke 22:19).

Here, I will assume that the OP is alluding to one or more of the following texts:

Rom 10:4 - Christ is the culmination of the law so that there may be righteousness for everyone who believes.
Matt 5:18 - For I tell you truly, until heaven and earth pass away, not a single jot, not a stroke of a pen, will disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished.

However, we also have other verse that "muddy the waters" on this subject such as:

Gal 5:14 - The entire law is fulfilled in a single decree: “Love your neighbor as yourself.”
Gal 6:2 - Carry one another’s burdens, and in this way you will fulfill the law of Christ.
Rom 13:8 - Be indebted to no one, except to one another in love. For he who loves his neighbor has fulfilled the law.
Rom 13:10 - Love does no wrong to its neighbor. Therefore, love is the fulfillment of the law.
Matt 7:12 - In everything, then, do to others as you would have them do to you. For this is the essence of the Law and the Prophets.

Indeed, Matthew records that Jesus said this:

Matt 5:17-19 - Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets. I have not come to abolish them, but to fulfill them. For I tell you truly, until heaven and earth pass away, not a single jot, not a stroke of a pen, will disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished. So then, whoever breaks one of the least of these commandments and teaches others to do likewise will be called least in the kingdom of heaven; but whoever practices and teaches them will be called great in the kingdom of heaven.

I agree that Jesus did fulfil the ordinance of the Passover and that this ordinance is eternal - and that is the point: Jesus is our Passover Lamb (1 Cor 5:7) and this same Jesus Christ who is the Passover Lamb is eternal, because He cannot die again, Rom 6:9.
Exactly the same can be said of all the rules and regulation surrounding the OT sanctuary and its High Priest

Jesus was the fulfilment of what the sanctuary/temple typified, John 2:19-21, Heb 9:1-28, 10:1-18
Jesus represented the foundation of the temple as well, 1 Peter 2:4-8 (Compare Isa 28:16, Ps 118:22)
Jesus’ body was represented by the curtain in the temple, Heb 10:20.
Jesus was the bread of life, John 6:35, 41, 48 (compare Ex 25:23-30, Lev 24:8).
Jesus was the light of life, John 8:12, 9:5 (compare the lampstand Ex 25:31-39, Lev 24:3, 4, Isa 53:11, Ps 56:13, etc)
Jesus provides the water of life, John 4:13, 14 (Compare the laver Ex 30:17-21.  See also 1 Cor 6:11)
Jesus is the promised seed of the woman Gal 3:16 (compare Gen 3:15, and the Abrahamic Covenant)
Jesus was the Passover Lamb and thus the promised Messiah, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 12:1-14).
Jesus is the High Priest of the New Covenant in fulfilment of the Levitical covenant, Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, because He was “pure, blameless, set apart” exactly as the Levites were.  See also Heb 9:15, 12:24.
Jesus provided the blood of the new covenant of which the communion ceremony was to be a memorial, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 24:5, 8).
Jesus was the anti-type of the “red heifer” (Num 19:1-10) and its associated ashes that “purify our consciences from works of death”, Heb 9:13, 14.



If Jesus was the fulfillment of the passover and did away with the sacrificial system and festivals, … ?

This is a somewhat loaded question; it assumes that Jesus did away with God's festivals.
In Acts 20:6, Paul waits until after the holy days before departing:

And we sailed away from Philippi after the days of unleavened bread … .

In 1 Corinthians 5, Paul describes the attitude Christians should have when celebrating the Feast of Unleavened Bread:

5:6 Your glorying is not good. Know ye not that a little leaven leaveneth the whole lump?
5:7 Purge out therefore the old leaven, that ye may be a new lump, as ye are unleavened. For even Christ our passover is sacrificed for us:
5:8 Therefore let us keep the feast, not with old leaven, neither with the leaven of malice and wickedness; but with the unleavened bread of sincerity and truth.

Similarly we see the celebration of Pentecost on several occasions:
Acts 2:1:

And when the day of Pentecost was fully come, they were all with one accord in one place.

Acts 20:16:

For Paul had determined to sail by Ephesus, because he would not spend the time in Asia: for he hasted, if it were possible for him, to be at Jerusalem the day of Pentecost.

1 Corinthians 16:8:

But I will tarry at Ephesus until Pentecost.

Acts 27:9 shows that Paul fasted on the Day of Atonement:

… because the fast was now already past, Paul admonished them,

John 7:8 shows Jesus telling the disciples to celebrate the Feast of Tabernacles:

Go ye up unto this feast ….

Zechariah 14:16 describes Tabernacles being kept in the Kingdom of God, even by the Gentile nations:

And it shall come to pass, that every one that is left of all the nations which came against Jerusalem shall even go up from year to year to worship the King, the LORD of hosts, and to keep the feast of tabernacles.


So yes, as these and other examples show, if Jesus had done away with God's holy festivals, there would be many contradictions.
The obvious conclusion is that Jesus did not do away with God's holy festivals.
There is no contradiction.

As others have mentioned, the operative word in the Exodus passage is עוֹלָם ('olam). This word is used in several contexts, one of which is G-d's eternality.
Psalm 90:2:

"Before the mountains were born or you brought forth the whole world, from everlasting to everlasting (מֵעוֹלָם וְעַד־עוֹלָם) you are G-d."

Isaiah 40:28:
"Do you not know? Have you not heard? The LORD is the everlasting (עוֹלָם 
) G-d, the Creator of the ends of the earth. He will not grow tired or weary, and his understanding no one can fathom."
Jeremiah 10:10:

"But the Lord is the true G-d; He is the living G-d and the everlasting King (עוֹלָם). At His wrath the earth trembles, and the nations cannot endure His indignation."

If the various commandments given by G-d (such as celebrating Passover) are everlasting, then yes anyone who abrogates them is contradicting scripture.

No. The better translation of Ex. 12:14 is from Young's.

`And this day hath become to you a memorial, and ye have kept it a feast to Jehovah to your generations; -- a statute age-during; ye keep it a feast.

Please note the instruction for the memorial feast was for the tribes of Israel, and for their generations, a statute "age-during."  That age was the Mosaic age, the same age which Jesus told His disciples would end with the destruction of the temple. His disciples knew that the destruction of the temple was the end of "the age."

2 and Jesus said to them, `Do ye not see all these? verily I say to you, There may not be left here a stone upon a stone, that shall not be thrown down.'


3 And when he is sitting on the mount of the Olives, the disciples came near to him by himself, saying, `Tell us, when shall these be? and what [is] the sign of thy presence, and of the full end of the age?'  (Matt. 24:2-3, YLT)

The destruction of Jerusalem and that temple was the end of the Mosaic age, the end of the Mosaic covenant which Christ told them would not pass until "heaven and earth" passed.  Since we are no longer under the Law of the Mosaic covenant, as Christ is our Passover (1 Cor. 5:7), as Christ is our Lamb sacrificed for our sins (1 Pet. 1:19; Rev. 5:12-13; 13:8), the Law has been fulfilled / completed, then "heaven and earth" has passed away.
Heaven and earth is an idiom, a phrase, a metaphor that God defined in Deu. 4:26 and 31:26 as the Mosiac covenant.

I have caused to testify against you this day the heavens and the earth, that ye do perish utterly hastily from off the land whither ye are passing over the Jordan to possess it; ye do not prolong days upon it, but are utterly destroyed; (Deu. 4:26, YLT)


`Take this Book of the Law, and thou hast set it on the side of the ark of the covenant of Jehovah your God, and it hath been there against thee for a witness; (Deu. 31:26, YLT)

The Mosaic Law was the creation of God for the covenant, the statutes between God and man, ie. "heaven and earth."  The Jews called the temple "heaven and earth" where God met with man.  So when Jesus said,

The heaven and the earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away. (Matt. 24:35, YLT)

He was telling His disciples in that prophesy of the destruction of the temple that the Mosiac covenant would pass away.  The disciples also knew Jesus was speaking about the temple being destroyed.  That age of the Mosaic covenant passed away when that temple was destroyed in AD 70.
The age-during time span of all of the feasts and statutes of the Law was fully complete, and juridically ended at the fall of that temple in AD 70.  And, the blessings Jacob had given to His children foretold it.  Gen. 49 laid out the end of each of the tribes of Israel, the last of which was Judah.

The sceptre turneth not aside from Judah, And a lawgiver from between his feet, Till his Seed come; And his [is] the obedience of peoples. (Gen. 49:10, YLT)

The scepter passed from the law-giver, from Judah to Christ in the first century AD, when His cousin John (the grandson of the last true Zadoc high priest) baptized Jesus in the Jordan river, and when Jesus was crucified on that cross, and when Jesus was the first fruits resurrected from the grave, and when He ascended into heaven to be seated at the right hand of the Father, and when He returned in judgment against those wicked who had crucified Him in the destruction of that city and temple in AD 70 just as He had promised them (Matt. 22, 24, 25).
All of the genealogical records that proved each tribes ancestry were stored in that temple, and were destroyed when it burned in AD 70. There is no longer any difference between a Jew and a gentile for those who are in Christ who are all now the Israel of God. (Gal. 3:26-29).
So, the translations that change "age-during" into "eternal" or "forever" are not accurate and are misleading.  There is no contradiction.
